# Low Events total days count

Tags: low, low-events

I might be missing it but.. is there a variable to output the total count of days the entry spans across, from start to finish?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [:duration](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events/docs/fieldtype#duration) modifier, but there is no modifier to output the number of days as an integer.